# Combining jQuery validate and jQuery Real Person

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to make sure all my required fields are filled in, however I was getting a lot of bot spam and want to use something like [jQuery Real Person](http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html) as a captcha system .

How do I combine the 2, so that t=submit will fail if the captcha field is not correct?

```
$("#enroll").validate({

                invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
                    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    if (errors) {
                        var message = errors == 1
                            ? 'You missed 1 required field.'
                            : 'You missed ' + errors + ' required fields';
                        $("div.Error span").html(message);
                        $("div.Error").show();
                    } else {
                        $("div.Error").hide();
                    }
                },
            });
```

The link, if relevant is [here](http://www.superscienceenrichment.com/index.php?cat=03&do=Enroll2)

Comment: The validation would need to be done on the server, not client. You should however at least mark the field as required.

Comment: It seems the test is on the server so you need to ajax the form submission

Comment: I did make it required, but how to I check if it is accurate?