# combine jquery validate and captcha

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, captcha

I'im using jquery validate (v. 1.13.1).
I'm also using a captcha [DEMO](http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/captcha/captcha.html)

I can't have both script to work together.

Only one similar question found here, unfortunately, no answer : 
[Combining jQuery validate and jQuery Real Person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326223/combining-jquery-validate-and-jquery-real-person)

Here's what I've done so far (the basic function, as all tests have failed..) :

```
$("#formsubmit").click(function(e){

$("#form-contact").validate({
 rules: {
        nom: "required",
        email: "required",
        tel: "required"
        }
    });

if($('ul').validate1() == true) {
        alert("Yeah, you are a human!")
        } else {
        alert("No, you are an alien !") }

});
```

Google was useless...
Can anyone help please ? some advice ?
TY

Comment: *"Only one similar question found"* ~ Not quite.  There are [more than 30 questions tagged "jQuery Validate" containing the word "captcha"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+captcha+is%3Aquestion).  Here's one with a detailed step-by-step answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396874/how-to-test-recaptcha-with-jquery-validate-plugin

Comment: BTW:  You should NEVER put the `.validate()` method inside the submit button's `click` handler.  The `.validate()` method is used for initializing the plugin and only belongs inside the DOM ready event handler.  Once initialized, the click of the button is captured automatically.  You must understand [the basic implementation of this plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) before you can integrate it to work with another plugin.